# AmazonS3Client.listObjects() issue with large s3bucket

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an issue with an s3bucket that contains thousands of entries, and the listing takes too much time.

As it is right now, I retrieve objects using;

```
ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);

foreach (S3Object entry in response.S3Objects.Where(p => p.Key.IndexOf(".mov") > 0 && DateTime.Parse(p.LastModified.ToString()) > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).OrderByDescending(k => k.LastModified))
{
     Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

With folder specification in the LIstObjectsRequest object through below code

```
 ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
                {
                    BucketName = "selectedbucket",
                    Prefix = "selectedfolder/",
                    MaxKeys = 2
                };
```

The time this simple retrieval takes is enormous (approx 7 minutes), so what I need to do is limit the results at actual request level instead of limiting AFTER retrieving all entries in the s3bucket.

Is there a way to speed this up by adding limiting criteria directly at the "client.ListObjects(request)" call? Can I add a criteria in the ListObjectsRequest object or something similar?

Thanks in advance for feedback and thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I increased the number of returned values by increasing Maxkeys to a higher amount (5000) instead of the previously defined 2. This limits the amount of calls as I understand it, which is what was taking time.

```
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
            {
                BucketName = "selectedbucket",
                Prefix = "selectedfolder/",
                MaxKeys = 5000
            };
```

This increased performance from 7 minutes down to about 2 seconds.

Comment: *This limits the amount of calls* -- not really "limits," but more correctly, "reduces."  `MaxKeys` *limits* the number of keys per response to not more than the number you pass, up to an actual maximum of 1000 so smaller values mean more requests (takes more time and costs more money) to fetch the same number of objects.  5000 is probably simply being ignored, since that is a larger value than S3 supports.  Specifying `MaxKeys` at all should not actually be needed, since the default when not specified is also the maximum 1000. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Michael-sqlbot